# GridView with ObjectDataSource Show Footer on Empty Data

Tags: asp.net, gridview, objectdatasource

There is no `ShowFooterWhenEmpty` property in GridView ;(

When I didn't use ObjectDataSource for data binding it was as simple as:

```
...
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable data = new DataTable();
    conn.Open();
    adapter.Fill(data);
    conn.Close();

    if (data.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        grid.DataSource = data;
        grid.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        data.Rows.Add(data.NewRow());
        grid.DataSource = data;
        grid.DataBind();

        int TotalColumns = grid.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
        grid.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
        grid.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
        grid.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = TotalColumns;
        grid.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "No Records Found";
    }
...
```

called by `Page_Load() if (!IsPostBack) {...}`

Now `ObjectDataSource` stands for auto-binding and paging.

How am I supposed to render the Footer where my Insert button located?

Tried `OnSelected` event of `ObjectDataSource` but I don't know how add a row in there.

```
protected void ODS_Selected(object sender, ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds = e.ReturnValue as DataSet;
    // Add empty row here or 'No Records Found' string to force Footer show
}
```

Help, please!

Comment: Why would you insist on having the information in footer if you have Empty Data Template?

Comment: There are insert button with related controls

Comment: You can have them duplicated in the empty data template.

Comment: Not sure if calls like (DropDownList)grid.FooterRow.FindControl("eventnoteDDL") will work then. Need to duplicate them another way?

Comment: That's why we switched to ListViews. You maintain the easy usage and bind to the same data sources but you get insert templates.

Answer (score 1):

As you already know the footer does not display when the GridView is empty (no rows). The work around is to ensure that a dummy row is returned from the ObjectDataSource when there is no real data present.

I would suggest checking the number of rows in the GridView DataBound event, if there are none, then modify the SelectMethod of the ObjectDataSource to return a dummy row of dummy data, and then re-bind the gridview. An example of dummy data could be:

```
ID : null
Name : 'No data, please add using form below' ...etc...
Description : null
...
etc
...
```

The GridView will then show the footer after the re-bind.

Comment: Seems this is the only quick-n-dirty SQL-level solution. Works well with gridview OnPreRender event to hide null values.